# Induction summation proof: $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{4}{5^{i}} < 1$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, geometric-series

Don't want a full answer but can somebody help me in the right direction with this problem. Have to prove using induction

> $$\forall n \geqslant 2: \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{4}{5^{i}} < 1$$

Comment: Prove by induction that the sum is $1-\frac{1}{5^n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an explicit formula like this
$$\begin{align}S&=\text{}\frac4{5}+&&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\frac4{5^2}+\ldots+\frac4{5^n}\\
\frac15S&=&&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\frac4{5^2}+\ldots+\frac4{5^3}+\frac4{5^{n+1}}\end{align}$$

Therefore $\displaystyle S-\frac15S=\frac45-\frac4{5^{n+1}}$ and $\displaystyle S=\frac{\frac45-\frac4{5^{n+1}}}{1-\frac15}=1-\frac1{5^n}<1$.

Now you can prove the $\displaystyle S=1-\frac1{5^n}$ by induction :)

Answer (score 1):

It's rather silly to use induction on this one (all you need is the sum of a geometric series), but if you insist:
if $S_n$ is your sum, express $S_{n+1}$ as $a + S_n/5$ for suitable $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Show that the difference between 1 and the previous sum is *always* greater than next term.

$$
Assume: 1 - \sum_1^{n - 1}\frac{4}{5^i} >  \frac{4}{5^n}
$$

If this is true?  Is it true for the next case well?
$$
next-case:1 - \sum_1^n \frac{4}{5^i} \stackrel{?}{>} \frac{4}{5^{n + 1}}
$$